# How to get me modal operator's mouse to jump across view3d region like with blender's built in scale operator?

Tags: python, operator

---

Is there a function built into blender that allows your mouse to infinitely scroll across the screen? I see this function on a lot of built in functions and was hoping to use it for mine. Below is a gif of my cursor jumping from edge region on the right to the edge of region on left and allowing me to continues scaling.

[image: scale operator]

Comment: You need to enable [use_mouse_continuous](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.PreferencesInput.html#bpy.types.PreferencesInput.use_mouse_continuous) in your modal operator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use in Operator :

```py
bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO', 'GRAB_CURSOR', 'BLOCKING'}
```

https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Operator.html#bpy.types.Operator.bl_options

Comment: This did it!! Thank you so much!!